# Shifting arrays without using loops

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, null, shift

I have been asked to equate two strings using recursion. Absolutely no loops are allowed. My idea is to check element by element, shrinking the string over time, but I don't know how to implement it. I want to delete the elements of the array once I check them, and then create a new string from the array in which the second element is now the first, and so on.

How does one do that?

Comment: You can use function recursion.

Comment: Recursion consists of defining two things: A base case (for example, if either string is "" we return immediately) and a recursion condition (for example, we reduce the character by one of both strings when we call ourselves, proving we eventually reach the base case). Then just add in logic to return true/false.

Comment: If you need recursion, you should try recursion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very common interview question, the logic goes like this:

```
isMatching(str1, str2, index):

  #check if they have same length, else return false at 1st call
  if(len(str1) != len(str2)) 
    return false                     #<-- termination step

  #if index crossed the length, that means all char in strings are over
  #we have already established that they have same length
  if(index > len(str1)) 
    return true                      #<-- termination step

  #compare char by char
  if(str1[index] == str2[index])
    isMatching(str1, str2, index+1)  #<-- propagation step
  else
    return false                     #<-- termination step
```

this recursion starts at index 1, the assumption is 1 based indexing of string. The above is just pseudo code.

You see the recursion is keep calling a function until a termination step is met, else it will go on calling the same function on and on with new index value to compare. So,

1. Look if the length are same, if not return false. End of story.
2. See if the index has crossed the length of one of the strings. Since we have already made sure that they must have the same length. Crossing index means, all the characters at each index has one-to-one match in the two strings. (see step 3).
3. Compare character at the index instructed. If it matches, go on.. call the function again, this time ask to compare the next index
4. if the index did not match, we have got a mismatch, terminate the process. The strings do not match, return false.

Comment: +1 - Very good answer + very well explained!

Answer (score 1):

```
int compareStrings(String s1,String s2,int curIndex)
{

    if(s1.length()==0 && s2.length()==0) return 0; // equal empty strings
    if(s1.length()==0 && s2.length()>0) return -1; // s1 is empty, s1<s2
    if(s1.length()>0 && s2.length()==0) return 1; // s2 is empty, s1>s2

    if(s1.charAt(curIndex)<s2.charAt(curIndex)) return -1;

    if(s1.charAt(curIndex)>s2.charAt(curIndex)) return 1;

    if(curIndex+1<Math.min(s1.length(),s2.length()))
    {
        return compareStrings(s1, s2, curIndex+1);
    }
    else
    {
        if(s1.length()==s2.length()) return 0;
        else if(s1.length()<s2.length()) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }


}
```

Function compareStrings return 0 if strings are equal, -1 if s1 lexicographically less than s2 and 1 if s1 >s2. Some test outputs:

```
    System.out.println(compareStrings("test","test",0)); // 0
    System.out.println(compareStrings("test","tesw",0)); // -1
    System.out.println(compareStrings("tesw","test",0)); // 1
    System.out.println(compareStrings("tesw","tes",0)); //1
    System.out.println(compareStrings("tes","tesw",0)); //-1
```